# Identifying reservation extensions in a dataset (ddply?)

Tags: r

I have a dataset of reservations, of which some are extensions of an original reservation. I'm trying to identify those extensions.

I keep flip-flopping between trying to do this in ddply or a 'for (row in data)' style loop, but in either case, I can't work out how to make the combination work.

These 3 checks will have to be done against every other row *in combination*. Ie for row 1, check row 2 for check-in/out date, building code, guestemail etc.

```
for (i in datax) {
  #1:length(fdr.list)
datax %>% filter(datax$email == datax[i,]$email)

# filter <- datax[datax$email == datax[i]$email]

datax[i, ]$Extension <- ifelse(data[i, ]$StaysOrdered == 1, 0, #Initial filtering just to do less work
     ifelse(
        floor_date(datax[i, ]$checkOutDate)== floor_date(datax$checkInDate) &
        datax[i, ]$buildingcode == datax$buildingcode &
          ifelse(not(is.na(datax[i, ]$email)),ifelse(datax[i, ]$email == datax$email
        , 1, 0),0)))
}
```

I don't have a reproducible example because I expect the logic in the middle to change and/or expand, and so I'm more looking for a base of code I can expand on rather than solve the issue outright.

This runs across ~30,000 reservations, so ideally the code won't take too long to row. I don't know how this would work, but maybe filter and then check by guestemail first?

Comment: Most of the times you don't need explicit `for` loop in R, there are functions that are developed that can perform such tasks but since you haven't provided any example it is difficult to test an answer which would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating some unique code strings and matching them. The big difference in time which brought it down from an hour to ~5 mins was putting the results in a pre-populated matrix rather than into a data.frame directly.

```
#Create unique codes to match; by three methods (email, lastname_cleaned, guest), one for check-out one for check-in
data$Extension_MatchCode_Email_Out <- paste(data$internaltitle, "-", floor_date(data$checkOutDate,"day"), "-", data$email)
data$Extension_MatchCode_Email_In <- paste(data$internaltitle, "-", floor_date(data$checkInDate,"day"), "-", data$email)
data$Extension_MatchCode_Name_Out <- paste(data$internaltitle, "-", floor_date(data$checkOutDate,"day"), "-", data$lastname_cleaned)
data$Extension_MatchCode_Name_In <- paste(data$internaltitle, "-", floor_date(data$checkInDate,"day"), "-", data$lastname_cleaned)
data$Extension_MatchCode_Guest_Out <- paste(data$internaltitle, "-", floor_date(data$checkOutDate,"day"), "-", data$guest)
data$Extension_MatchCode_Guest_In <- paste(data$internaltitle, "-", floor_date(data$checkInDate,"day"), "-", data$guest)

#Prepopulate results matices. We don't want to be writing into the dataframe directly else it will be ~8x slower
matchval_email <- rep(NA, nrow(data))
matchval_lastname <- rep(NA, nrow(data))
matchval_guest <- rep(NA, nrow(data))

#For loop; for each row check if there is a match in another row's 'in' column to the row's 'out' column. Every 100 loops, print progress and time stamp.
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
ifelse(i %% 100 == 0, print(paste(i, "-", Sys.time())),"")

#Match by customer email method
matchval_email[i] <- ifelse(is.na(data[i, ]$email), 0, #Check if email is blank, if so, skip
                              ifelse(data[i, ]$Stays_Email <2, 0, #Check if stays for this email is <2, if so, skip
                              fmatch(data[i, ]$Extension_MatchCode_Email_In, data$Extension_MatchCode_Email_Out, nomatch = 0))) #find first occurance of a match for out to in code.
#Match by last name method
matchval_lastname[i] <- ifelse(is.na(data[i, ]$lastname_cleaned), 0,
                              ifelse(data[i, ]$Stays_LastName_Cleaned <2, 0,
                              fmatch(data[i, ]$Extension_MatchCode_Name_In, data$Extension_MatchCode_Name_Out, nomatch = 0)))
#Match by guest code method
matchval_guest[i] <- ifelse(is.na(data[i, ]$guest), 0,
                              ifelse(data[i, ]$Stays <2, 0,                               
                              fmatch(data[i, ]$Extension_MatchCode_Guest_In, data$Extension_MatchCode_Guest_Out, nomatch = 0)))

}


#Move matrix results into dataframe once
data$matchval_email <- matchval_email
data$matchval_lastname <- matchval_lastname
data$matchval_guest <- matchval_guest
```